# How to print the variable inside the function

Tags: python

My code is below. trying to print the `htmlStr` inside the function. Is there any way

```
import urllib.request
import re
url = 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees'
def testhtml(self):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    htmlStr = response.read().decode('ISO-8859-1')
    with open("html.csv","a+") as file:
        file.write(htmlStr)
    pdata = re.findall(r'"employee_name":"(\'?\w+)"', htmlStr)
    return pdata
```

print (htmlStr) I did outside the function thrown error

when I did `print (htmlStr)` got the error `NameError: name 'htmlStr' is not defined`

[image]

Comment: The given code is working fine for me and I'm able to print `htmlStr` inside the function. Can you attach a screenshot of the error when you run your code?

Comment: (1) "htmlStr" is a local variable and doesn't exist outside of the function. (2) You should primarily show the code that doesn't work, not the code that works (3) Despite the request from @AjayDabas you should show errors and output as properly formatted text in the question, not as image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an error because you're trying to access a local variable outside of its domain.

Here's what this looks like in your code:

```
# 1. Begin creating your function
def testhtml(self):
    # 2. This is a local environment. 
    #    Any variables created here will not be accessible outside of the function
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    # 3. The local variable `htmlStr` is created.
    htmlStr = response.read().decode('ISO-8859-1')
    with open("html.csv","a+") as file:
        # 4. Your local variable `htmlStr` is accessed.
        file.write(htmlStr)
    pdata = re.findall(r'"employee_name":"(\'?\w+)"', htmlStr)
    return pdata

# 5. Your function is now complete. The local variable `htmlStr` is no longer accessible.
```

*Does that make sense?* 
If you want to print your function (while debugging) you can place a print statement in the function. *(Just make sure to eventually remove it to prevent disorganized console readouts.)* If you need to access the variable outside of the function, consider including in the output.